# Using map or flatMap on a pattern matched output value

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

So I was trying to use pattern matching like this.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val opt = Some(null)
opt match {
  case Some(null) => None
  case _ => opt
}.map(_.toString)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:5: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
}.map(_.toString)
 ^
```

But that doesn't work. While this does,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val opt = Some(null)
val matchedOpt = opt match {
  case Some(null) => None
  case _ => opt
}
matchedOpt.map(_.toString)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

opt: Some[Null] = Some(null)
matchedOpt: Option[Null] = None
res10: Option[String] = None
```

So my questions are,

1. Why does one work but not the other?
2. Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: better way to do this to say `case any => any.map(_.toString)`  instead of `case _ => opt`

Comment: You can do Option(null).map(_.toString)

Comment: @Nyavro: I get `Some(null)` from a different function and whatever I have presented here is just for presenting the problem. I know `Option(null)` returns `None`.

Comment: @Łukasz: That does seem better. Thanks!

Comment: `opt.flatMap(Option.apply).map(_.toString)`

Comment: @Lee Wonderful. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: To answer your first question, you should wrap the pattern matching in parentheses, like so:
`(opt match {
  case Some(null) => None
  case _ => opt
}).map(_.toString)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Option.apply(null)` returns `None` you can use `flatMap` to remove `null` values and map over the result:

```
opt.flatMap(Option.apply).map(_.toString)
```